# Create Isolated environment for running binaries from users in a docker environment

Tags: linux, security, google-cloud-platform

I'd like to process user submitted executable (made with PyInstaller under linux environment) in my Cloud Run instance in a safe way. The executable also have some files that needs to process in the same folder, which are downloaded through my cloud storage. Since Cloud Run is also in a Docker environment, it looks quite troublesome to run a Docker inside a Docker especially if it comes to Cloud Run since I can't modify the Docker RUN command that starts Cloud Run if I am not mistaken. Invoking other Cloud Run instance in this case not applicable because it could serve multiple request and multiple user submitted executable could affect each other and also user code access my cloud run service's code and modify cloud storage. I have some thought about alternative approaches please share your thought about them..

1. I could somehow restrict privileges of my cloud run service's access
   to my cloud storage, limit concurrent invocations of the same
   service, and start with a proper clean up everytime the service
   starts/being reused.
2. Call the binary with restricted priviliges like using chroot,fork limitation,watchdog (Not sure if these are enough to be safe)
3. Create some kind of isolated envrionment for the script and the input files, run it and get the result back. (this would be easy
   with docker, just using a binding so host can provide the input
   files and gather the result file)

I am open to other ideas and aswell detailed thought about my alternative ones.

Answer (score 0):

Build and test each submission. Not in the Cloud Run instance, but some build system. You expressed a preference for containers, and yes they make a lot of sense for isolation.

Your application gathers source code, generates a build configuration, adds tests, and starts a build. Possibly the build system deploys the result somewhere for further processing or use.

Perhaps [GCP Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build). Has the advantages of being fairly extensible, and can pull GCP storage and container artifacts.

Comment: So you suggest that I should do a 0th step by making a test system that looks for malicious code in the user's submission, and then build it with pyinstaller into an executable?

Comment: You did not specify what the build or processing steps involve.  Essentially, use a CI/CD pipeline. Up to you whether the analysis work is done in a test phase, or post deployment.

Comment: I feel like using these services are overkill a bit. a single python file can be made into an executable by 3 quick steps: checking requirements, iinstalling requirements, pyinstaller with --onefile switch. These steps are already done for me.

Comment: That's the build step. You described additional requirements of analysis in isolation.  Do these however you want. You could script creating a container or VM somewhere, grabbing sources from cloud buckets and repos, running the build and test scripts, and reporting success or failure.   Or you could hook into a system which specializes in testing in isolation. One of those custom built vs use another product decisions.